# Why are there no increment and decrement operators in Rust?

Tags: rust

The `++` and `--` operators are included in many other languages. Why did the language designers choose not to include these operators in Rust?

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415083).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are not included in Rust as they can lead to subtle bugs because they require complex knowledge about evaluation order, especially when combined into larger expressions as shown below. Can you guess what these two C++ programs print? I guessed wrong.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    int a = 4;
    int b = 4;
    int c = a++ + b++;
    printf ("%i %i %i", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    int z = ++x + x++;
    printf ("%i %i", x, z);
    return 0;
}
```

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/dtolnay/rust-faq#why-doesnt-rust-have-increment-and-decrement-operators):

> **Why doesn't Rust have increment and decrement operators?**
>
> Preincrement and postincrement (and the decrement equivalents), while
> convenient, are also fairly complex. They require knowledge of
> evaluation order, and often lead to subtle bugs and undefined behavior
> in C and C++. x = x + 1 or x += 1 is only slightly longer, but
> unambiguous.

Comment: I actually think the behavior of the line `int z = ++x + x++;` is undefined in the C++ standard as I found a blog post where it was stated that this should print `12 22`, but in the online compiler I used[1], this prints `12 23`.

[0]: https://hackernoon.com/increment-and-decrement-operators-in-cc-6c1c3u63
[1]: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler, this

Comment: IIRC this (`a++ + b++`, `++x + x++`) is undefined behavior. Not sure about that though.

Comment: It is worth noting that while in Rust assignments _are_ expressions, they always return the unit type `()`, which prevents whole another class of bugs. Because of that, we could support either of them (there is no reason to support both) but return a unit type (like Go does), but the language designers decided it makes no real difference with `x += 1`.

Comment: `a++ + b++` is well defined: the compiler may choose in which order it evaluates `a++` and `b++` and whether it computes the addition first before incrementing `a` and `b` or whether it stores the original values of `a` and `b` in temporaries and increments them before performing the addition, but all those will result in `a=b=5` and `c=8`.

Comment: `++x + x++` is ill defined: the compiler may choose to evaluate the increments and the addition in whatever order, which may result in `z` being 21, 22 or 23 depending on the order chosen.

Comment: @Jmb Even worse, `z` can be 0 or 50, and the rest of the program malfunction, because `++x + x++` is UB.

Comment: @user4815162342 I think in older versions of the C standard it was simply "unspecified", not "undefined". But you're right, at least in [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), it is indeed "undefined" and so may result in anything at all (section 6.5).

Comment: @Jmb Sometimes it's hard to believe just _how_ easy C and C++ make it to shoot oneself in the foot. I seem to remember `++x + x++` being decried as UB back in the 90s and, while I don't trust my memory too far in such matters, resources like [this 90s FAQ](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html) or [this 2009 SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior) seem to corroborate it.